# node_load loads from revision

Tags: views, nodes

I have came across this error for a few times now, and i don't know why it happens.

I have created a view, in which i show node data. Nothing special... Data is obviously loaded from "node" table. But when i run

```
    node_load()
```

i get different data!? I checked, and it is from node_revision table.

Why is that? How can i fix this?

thanks

Comment: Always node and node_revision tables are updated together.. Node table always contains latest data.. For Example , if your node is unpromoted from front page both node and active revision of node in node and node_revision table contains same value.. If there exists different value from active revision in node table it means some custom module / Custom Configuration like rules is responsible for this behaviour...

Comment: My node and node revision are not sync. For this example, i have one record in node and one in node_revision and they are not the same.

Comment: Did you create custom module/custom content type?